# Is there an issue with closing our database connections in the "Finally" block of a Try statement?

Tags: java, exception-handling, resources

I'm doing some refactoring for our application, and trying to reduce the number of issues reported in our ISO Scan (a static code analysis tool based on HP Fortify).  Right now, what I'm trying to address is the "Unreleased Resource: Database" issues our application has built up.  One of the most prominent reasons for this is constructs like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
Boolean myConn = false;
try{
   if(conn == null){
     conn = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
     myConn = true;
   }
   result = DbClass.getObject(conn, otherParameters);
}catch(DatabaseException de){
  throw de;
}catch(SQLException sqle){
  throw new DatabaseException("Error Message");
}finally{
  if(myConn && conn != null){
    try{
      conn.rollback();
      conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){}
}
```

This is a fairly standard construct in our application to ensure the database connection is closed at the end of our Try block.  Yet every time we use it, the tool reports it as an issue.

Is there anything incorrect about this construct, and is there anything we can do to fix it if it is an issue?

Comment: java7? if so go with try-with-resources

Comment: What does your ISO scan complain about, other than the construct's existence? Does it come with some sort of explanation as to why it's a problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey They haven't complained about it so far, but because it's a large application, it's a significant portion of the issues reported by our scan (Diplomatically, less than 9999) and it concerns *me* because I'm wondering if there's a reason beyond it not recognizing the explicit close in the Finally block, which upon reviewing the ISO report is **exactly** how it recommends handling this issue.

Comment: Forgive me for being ignorant, but what exactly is an ISO scan?  Can you post a unique portion of the error message so that I have something Googlable?

Comment: I'd guess that it is reported as an issue because you use a conditional close, i.e. only when you opened it yourself. This construct probably outsmarted the code analysis, which thinks that the connection might be left open.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry for not being clear - It's actually the HP Fortify tool that our ISO department makes us use that reports this issue. Not our ISO group itself (which Is responsible for making sure we're ISO (International Organizational Standards) compliant).

Comment: According to [this example Fortify security report](http://wiki.dd.ncu.edu.tw/mediawiki/images/c/c9/ECard_-_Fortify_Security_Report.pdf), Fortify actually recommends that you release resources in a `finally` block.

Comment: In addition to what @StevenPessall said, you're releasing resources in another `try` block, so execution is not guaranteed from a static code analysis perspective.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Would eliminating the try block be recommended?  Or would it expose us to the possibility of an uncaught, unhandled exception?

Comment: Why does the variable `myConn` need to exist? Also, I doubt you need to rollback. That should be the default if you don't commit.

Comment: @usr I'm not sure about that second part (really, I'm not sure, can anyone back this up?) but the first part I agree is superfluous, unless someone can think of a good reason to use it.

Comment: NO, rollback is not the default when closing a connection. If it will rollback, depends on the jdbc/connection pool used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And the tools are right!

Apart from the (possible) limitations of the analysis - it may or may not understand that `(conn != null) == myConn`, observe that `rollback` throws an `SqlException`. If it does, then *`close` is never called*, which is precisely the definition of a resource leak. Now, it may be the case that with your *current* DB, drivers and pooling libraries if `rollback` throws, then the connection is already released, but this is not true in the general case, hence a potential problem.

As noted in comments you can simplify much of this construct by using `try-with-resources` if using Java 7. It also becomes much simpler to reason about and include a rollback via a custom class that does rollback in its `close()` method in a try block:

```
@Override
public void close() throws SQLException {
    try {
        rollback();
    catch (...) {
        //Do stuff
    finally {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Here you are 100% guaranteed that `close()` will actually run, whatever `rollback` does.

If working with legacy software, the above code can be directly put into the `try`:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
   conn = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
   result = DbClass.getObject(conn, otherParameters);
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
  throw new DatabaseException("Error Message");
} finally {
  if (conn != null) {
    try{
        conn.rollback();
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        //try-with-resources would add this to suppressed exceptions, you can either log or rethrow
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally an answer with `try-with-resources`. It has only been around since [2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7_.28July_28.2C_2011.29) and was designed specifically for cases like this.

Comment: Sadly working with Legacy application, so not up to Java 7 yet.  But this *will* be useful when we're up to that version (and for anyone who has Java 7) and offers a good suggestion for those of us (me) who aren't.

Comment: @Zibbobz The semantics of `try-with-resources` are well-known, and while not directly translatable to Java 6, you can get very close. I answered a couple of such [questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611940/try-with-resources-equivalent-in-java-1-6/23612120#23612120). Oracle put an explanation up ages ago with the *full* [semantics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html): in essence you would put another `try` in the `finally` block, with `rollback()` in the body and `close()` in the inner `finally`

Comment: @Snowman don't get your hopes up. The .NET people have this for 15 years and still don't always use it. It boggles the mind.

Comment: @usr I know, you can only provide the tools. But any answer that spreads the knowledge is good, it just might help someone who does not realize the tool is there.

Comment: I've tried this, and I get an error saying that .close throws an SQLException.  Is it acceptable to just add another Try block to catch said exception (which in the comments of the close method suggest it's simply in case the connection cannot be established while closing) or should I just leave it in the first Try block, and accept that our application requires both .rollback and .close to have SQLException catching on our DatabaseConnection connections?

Comment: Optionally, I could also pass on the responsibility of catching the error to the methods that call this class, but managing that could become more complicated than it's realistically worth.  If I have to though, I will do it.

Comment: @Zibbobz Ah, I forgot you're wrapping all exceptions in a `DatabaseException`. You'd need to handle the case of `close` throwing it as well then (either by wrapping too, or `throws` on the method). Don't forget - you might *not* want to wrap and rethrow it if you've already got an exception from the `try` body or `rollback` (as that would mask the original)! The oracle blog from my comment above has the "proper" structure to use to catch and deal with all exceptions, and it is a horrendous 3-layered `try` - one of the reasons twr was made.

Comment: In trying to implement this, I find that conn.commit() can also throw an SQLException error.  Should I use the same methodology with commit attempts that I do with rollbacks? (Which is to say: catching them and then making sure the conn.Close() is inside of its own Finally block, the same way you show in your code sample how to handle rollbacks).

Comment: @Zibbobz I would *not* put `commit()` into the finally block. Consider this - if your code is doing a multistage operation, and one of the stages throws an exception - do you really want to commit the partial (and possibly invalid) result? `commit()` is typically the last statement of the `try` body, and its exceptions would be handled just like those of all the other "normal" statements.

Answer (score 5):

Because your release of resources is conditional on the state of a boolean variable and encased in another `try` block, the static analyzer must be deciding that `rollback()` and `close()` are not guaranteed to execute.

Check the documentation for the `Connection` object of the type returned by the `getConnection()` factory method, and see if the methods `rollback()` and `close()` will even throw an exception.  If they won't, you don't need that additional `try` `catch` block when calling those methods.

But first, eliminate the boolean variable that you're using to signal an open connection.  You shouldn't need it; you shouldn't get a connection object back from the `getConnection()` factory method unless it was successful at establishing a connection.

Note that Fortify's security report suggests the following code structure:

```
public void execCxnSql(Connection conn) {
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(CXN_SQL);
        ...
    } 
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            safeClose(stmt);
        }
    }
}
public static void safeClose(Statement stmt) {
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

...which suggests that the boolean variable is the problem, not the additional `try` block.

Comment: I'll have to try this, and see if it resolves the issue - if not, it might just be an oversight in the HP Fortify Rulespack that we're using.

Comment: Of course, it would be way better to just use a `try(resource){` block (try-with-resource). Assuming you can run Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the condition, since the compiler things the code could not run at all.

Then catch `Exception` instead of `SQLException` so it catches `NullPointerException` in case the connections are not initialized. I usually set the object to null after closing it, because a recommendation I read in a Sybase's EAServer paper and, maybe,  it has nothing to do with Java's garbage collector but with EAServer's connection pool, and maybe I'm *"cargo-culting"* here.

```
Connection conn = null;
Boolean myConn = false;
try{
   if(conn == null){
     conn = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
     // myConn = true; no need for this
   }
   result = DbClass.getObject(conn, otherParameters);
}catch(DatabaseException de){
  throw de;
}catch(SQLException sqle){
  throw new DatabaseException("Error Message");
}finally{
    try{
      conn.rollback();
      conn.close();
      conn=null; // good practice according to people at Sybase
    }catch(Exception e){
         //fails silently when conn is not initialized.
    }
}
```

Comment: "a recommendation I read somewhere" is not really a good thing to repeat to other people :) It's to do with the fact that the JVM won't release or finalize the object until either it's dereferenced or out of scope. So the memory associated with the connection (and all data returned), as well as any (possible) native resources would linger until you exit the method - potentially a long time if you do more work in the method!

Comment: @Ordous I added a mention to where I read that (I already had done it in the code's comment).

Comment: I never worked at or with Sybase or their products, yet I was given the same recommendation. Some of the answers on Javas garbage collection reaffirmed this, as well as the other suggestion I've been made - don't do anything in DB access methods except DB access. Maybe EAServer has other reasons for this as well, but it does seem like solid advice anyway.